# Jquery clone div add new delete button

Tags: jquery

Here is the html code

```
<div id="input1" class="clonedInput">
<div class="col-sm-3 text_flied">
    <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding">
        <input type="" class="form-control banwidth frmfld" value=""   name="from_width[1]" id="widthid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text_middle no-padding">
    <p>X</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding">
        <input type="" class="form-control banheight frmfld" value=""   name="from_height[1]" id="heightid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 no-padding arrow_text">
    <img src="/futurebanner/dev/themes/onlinetest/images_front/down_arrow1.png" class="arrow_text ban_size">
    </div>
    <div class="size-drop-center"  style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="88" banheight="31" ><span>88</span><em>x</em><span>31</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="120" banheight="60" ><span>120</span><em>x</em><span>60</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="120" banheight="90"><span>120</span><em>x</em><span>90</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="120" banheight="240"><span>120</span><em>x</em><span>240</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="125" banheight="125"><span>125</span><em>x</em><span>125</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="160" banheight="600"><span>160</span><em>x</em><span>600</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="234" banheight="60"  ><span>234</span><em>x</em><span>60</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="468" banheight="60"  ><span>468</span><em>x</em><span>60</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="728" banheight="90"  ><span>728</span><em>x</em><span>90</span></a></li>
<li class="custom"><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="" banheight=""  >custom size</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-7 no-padding-right">
    <div class="text_checkbox">
    <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding">
    <div class="checkbox" style="float:left;">
        <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="chk-animated frmfld animclass" name="is_animated[1]" value="15">+$15Animated
        </label>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding-right">

    <div class="checkbox" style="float:left;">
        <label>
                 <input type="checkbox" class="chk-animated frmfld timclass" name="is_timings[1]" value="10">+$10 /24H 
        </label>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding">
    <div class="checkbox" style="float:left;">
        <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="chk-animated frmfld  psdclass" name="is_psd[1]" value="5">+$5 .PSD
        </label>
      </div>
      </div>    
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 no-padding-right">
    <div class="text_total pull-left">
    $<span class="tot" id="res_tot1">0</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
    </div><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnAdd">+ ADD BANNER</button>
```

Here is the jquery code

```
 $('#btnAdd').on('click',function() {
                    var num     = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have

                    var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added
                    $("#num_banner").html(newNum);
                    // replace the input name as input1, input2
                    var newaddress= $('.clonedInput').last().clone(true).attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

                    newaddress.find('.frmfld').each(function() {
                        this.name= this.name.replace('['+num+']', '['+newNum+']');
                    });

                    newaddress.find('.tot').each(function() {
                        this.id= this.id.replace(num, newNum);
                    });


                    //$('#input' + num).after(newaddress);
                    $('.clonedInput').last().after(newaddress);

                    findtotalamount();
                    calc_deliverydate();

            });
```

When i click the add banner button, it clones the "clonedInput" div class. Initially, we don't need to include delete button. But after click the add banner , I need to add the following delete button code in the cloned divs

```
<div class="pull-left del-area"><a href="#" id="del_banner"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
</div>
```

How to add the above line in the cloned div only?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate IDs in your HTML.

Comment: You are cloning the div in your code already, so why don't you add the new element to it in the same place? ie: `myClonedDiv.append(myDeleteButton)`.

Comment: i need to add the delete buttton, in between the "<div id="input1" class="clonedInput">" and "<div class="col-sm-3 text_flied">". By default, no need to display the delete button. but  delete button displays only after clicking the add banner button only.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution for you . [***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/2gs6gjk4/)

I have added `myClass` to `X` div class,but you can use existing class for the same purposed also depending if you are not using those class for other things.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the button in the markup for the the original `.clonedInput` and using css you can hide the button since you do not want to delete the first(original) div. As you can see, I changed `id="del_banner"` to `class="del_banner"` so you don't end up with duplicate IDs. And you really don't need the IDs anyway.

```
<div class="pull-left del-area"><a href="#" class="del_banner"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
```

In the add callback, you can add the following line, which will show all copied `.del_banner` elements -- but not the `:first`.

```
$('div.del-area').not(':first').show();
```

Then you can add a click event listener to `a.del_banner` as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.del_banner', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.cInput').remove();
});
```

Check out the demo; it works! :)

```js
$('#btnAdd').on('click',function() {
                    var num     = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have

                    var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added
                    $("#num_banner").html(newNum);
                    // replace the input name as input1, input2
                    var newaddress= $('.clonedInput').last().clone(true).attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

                    newaddress.find('.frmfld').each(function() {
                        this.name= this.name.replace('['+num+']', '['+newNum+']');
                    });

                    newaddress.find('.tot').each(function() {
                        this.id= this.id.replace(num, newNum);
                    });


                    //$('#input' + num).after(newaddress);
                    $('.clonedInput').last().after(newaddress);
                    
                    $('div.del-area').not(':first').show();
  
                    findtotalamount();
                    calc_deliverydate();

            });

$(document).on('click', 'a.del_banner', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.cInput').remove();
});
```

```css
div.del-area {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input1" class="clonedInput cInput">
<div class="col-sm-3 text_flied">
    <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding">
        <div class="pull-left del-area"><a href="#" class="del_banner">DEL<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
</div>
        <input type="" class="form-control banwidth frmfld" value=""   name="from_width[1]" id="widthid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 text_middle no-padding">
    <p>X</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding">
        <input type="" class="form-control banheight frmfld" value=""   name="from_height[1]" id="heightid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 no-padding arrow_text">
    <img src="/futurebanner/dev/themes/onlinetest/images_front/down_arrow1.png" class="arrow_text ban_size">
    </div>
    <div class="size-drop-center"  style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="88" banheight="31" ><span>88</span><em>x</em><span>31</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="120" banheight="60" ><span>120</span><em>x</em><span>60</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="120" banheight="90"><span>120</span><em>x</em><span>90</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="120" banheight="240"><span>120</span><em>x</em><span>240</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="125" banheight="125"><span>125</span><em>x</em><span>125</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="160" banheight="600"><span>160</span><em>x</em><span>600</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="234" banheight="60"  ><span>234</span><em>x</em><span>60</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="468" banheight="60"  ><span>468</span><em>x</em><span>60</span></a></li>
<li><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="728" banheight="90"  ><span>728</span><em>x</em><span>90</span></a></li>
<li class="custom"><a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="ban_text" banwidth="" banheight=""  >custom size</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-7 no-padding-right">
    <div class="text_checkbox">
    <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding">
    <div class="checkbox" style="float:left;">
        <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="chk-animated frmfld animclass" name="is_animated[1]" value="15">+$15Animated
        </label>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding-right">

    <div class="checkbox" style="float:left;">
        <label>
                 <input type="checkbox" class="chk-animated frmfld timclass" name="is_timings[1]" value="10">+$10 /24H 
        </label>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding">
    <div class="checkbox" style="float:left;">
        <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="chk-animated frmfld  psdclass" name="is_psd[1]" value="5">+$5 .PSD
        </label>
      </div>
      </div>    
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 no-padding-right">
    <div class="text_total pull-left">
    $<span class="tot" id="res_tot1">0</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
    </div><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnAdd">+ ADD BANNER</button>
```